# Problem with visual studio working for c # and c ++?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

It happens that you download Visual Studio 2019 for use with C# and C++, install it by selecting the workload for C# and C++.

[image]
But then when I enter the environment and go to the create project part, none of the templates I need appear. I don't even get the most basic one, which is the template for creating a console application with C#.

[image]

I assumed that if you choose the installation for C# and C++ those templates should come by default, but it does not happen ..

What do I need to configure so that the templates I need to start programming visual studio appear?

Comment: It would help greatly if you could show which workloads you selected during installation (you can get this by modifying the existing installation via Programs and Features) as a screenshot, and also show a screenshot of VS' new project screen.

Comment: What happens if you filter by language C++?

Comment: It's kind of fun that the terribly broken new project screen cannot even find a C# console application when explictly search for "console application".

Answer (score 0):

Search for "console app" or just "console" and they will appear.  These templates do not include the word "application" in their title or description.